# When does EFCore OnModelCreating get invoked?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

I know it gets called when you **create** Migrations, but is that the *ONLY* time it's called?

It seems unlike that it is called when a request comes in (in the context of a WebApi system), but does it get called on server startup? Or during the deployment process at any point? Or during Migration **running**?

Asking for data-seeding purposes, though I'd like to know the answer in the abstract too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum, the method is also called when applying Migrations, which is often configured to be automatically done on WebHost Startup.
At a guess, this is because EF attempts to validate the Database state, before performing migrations. That validation appears to demand a model for comparison, thus the method is run.

There may be other occassions on which it runs.

Answer (score 3):

`OnModelCreating` is called by the framework when it is created the first time to make the models and map into memory. It provides you a way to configure the model class using fluent API. So you make changes in the model class and then add migration and update the database. The generated Snapshot gives you the exact details about the database. It does not get called during the program execution.

Comment: Further research demonstrates that this is incorrect. The method is called on program start, in order that EF can validate the current state of the database.

Comment: You are wrong , u try one thing. You do some changes in any table in OnModelCreating and then run the application. And u make the same change in snapshot and then run the app

Comment: See clarification in my response. I guarantee you that OnModelCreating is getting run when I start the program ;)

Comment: Yes. We did. That's how I know that this answer is wrong.

Comment: The answer is not wrong. If the methods are called on program start, it is because you have specifically configured EntityFramework to be accessed on app start.